# Jack the rabbit and joint distribution probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

I've ran across this problem in my textbook, really don't know how to solve it.

[image]

Answer: .3973

**What I've tried:**

Since the rabbit's location is uniformly distributed, and depends on both an x and y coordinate  I get f(x,y) = $\frac{1}{40*80}=\frac{1}{3200}$

The area of ellipse is $\pi(20)(30)$ = 1885

the area of the triangle is (.5)(40)(40) = 800

meaning the total prohibited area is 1885+800 = 2685.

This means that there's a $\frac{2685}{3200}$ probability of Jack the rabbit getting eating or hit with a sling shot. Or $\frac{3200-2685}{3200}$ = $\frac{515}{3200}$ = .161

I know this is clearly wrong, and the technique isn't the best. I'd assume the proper/best technique invokes double integrals. However, when I consider this I'm unsure how to set the limits of integration, without summing multiple double integrals.

$\int_0^{30}$ $\int_{0}^{20}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx to represent the area that's safe below the ellipses.

$\int_{30}^{40}$ $\int_{0}^{40}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx to represents the area that's safe between the ellipses and the triangle.

$\int_{40}^{80}$ $\int_{0}^{40}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx to represent the safe area above the triangle.

Computing these and summing these results in;

$\int_0^{30}$ $\int_{0}^{20}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx +  $\int_{40}^{80}$ $\int_{0}^{40}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx + $\int_{40}^{80}$ $\int_{0}^{40}$ $\frac{1}{3200}$ dydx = $\frac{3}{16}$ + $\frac{1}{8}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{13}{16}$ = .8125

I really have no idea how else to do this, but I'm assuming my limits of integration are way off.

Comment: On the contrary, I much prefer your first approach. It is immediate from definitions that the double integrals reduce to areas in this case. Simple geometric formulae for areas are easier to understand and explain better where the final probability comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the entire ellipse is about $1885$, but only a quarter of the ellipse matters. $$\frac{\frac{1}{4} \pi \cdot 20 \cdot 30 + 800}{3200} \approx 0.3973. $$ (I think there's a mistake, though; 39% is the probability that the rabbit is *not* safe, not the probability that it is safe.)